# Timer to perform task in Python --CLOSED--

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I know this question is not that good but I am kind of stuck here and I've been searching about timers but the answers are just not what I am looking for.

Okay so I have a `for loop` here and this `for loop` is trying to do something continuously but I need it to do its task for a minute that I have chosen and let's say 3 minutes , so it would be like

```
for i in sample_iteration:
   #Tasks are being done here
```

But I need those tasks inside the for loop to keep going for 3 minutes and I have found this timer from [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/) and this is the code

```
# import the time module 
import time 

# define the countdown func. 
def countdown(t): 
    
    while t: 
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
        print(timer, end="\r") 
        time.sleep(1) 
        t -= 1
    
    print('Fire in the hole!!') 


# input time in seconds 
t = input("Enter the time in seconds: ") 

# function call 
countdown(int(t))
```

Now I tried this one right here, now it does the countdown for 3 minutes but it also does the time.sleep(1) for one second and I can't have it paused for every second cause I need to to keep going as **possible**.

```
t = 180 #seconds
for i in sample_iteration:
    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
    timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
    print(timer, end="\r") 
    time.sleep(1) 
    t -= 1
    
    #Do the task here
```

**I can easily I think make a condition that when t is 0 I could break the loop**

Now long ago I had this java program that does the work and involves some nano time with I understand this and the counting is based on nano time cause 100000000 nanoseconds is equal to 1 second right? (correct me if I am wrong) so yeah and here is the code

```
public class Timer {
    
       public static void main(String[] args){
       
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        boolean running = true;
        int timer = 0;
        long now ;
       int i = 0;
        while(running)   
        {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            timer += (now - lastTime);
            lastTime = now;
            
            if(timer >= 1000000000)
            {
             i++;
              timer = 0; 
              System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        
       }
       
}
```

I was thinking of doing the same with python but I'm getting lost to be honest and I am just a beginner and tried to get help here in this great community! Also maybe there's an alternative where I do not have to apply based on the java program cause maybe there's a **better way and shorter way** with python. Thank you! Looking forward for this THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---UPDATE---

Hello I managed to figure it out! Thanks for the answers this is what I've done

```
i = 0
lastTime = time.time_ns()
timer = 0

for i in sample_iteration:
    now = time.time_ns()
    timer += (now - lastTime)
    lastTime = now

    if timer >= 1000000000:
        i+=1
        timer = 0
        print(i)
```

I used the `time.time_ns()` to get the nanoseconds cause `time.time()` is different vs `time.time_ns()`. `time.time()` is getting the time in seconds since the epoch and it is not in nano seconds which is what I was looking for

**time.time_ns()** method of Time module is used to get the time in nanoseconds since the epoch. To get the time in seconds since the epoch, we can use **time.time()** method.

The epoch is the point where the time starts and is **platform dependent**. On Windows and most Unix systems, the epoch is **January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC)** and leap seconds are not counted towards the time in seconds since the epoch. To check what the epoch is on a given platform we can use time.gmtime(0).

Source: [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-time-time_ns-method/#:%7E:text=time_ns()%20method%20of%20Time,starts%20and%20is%20platform%20dependent.)

Thank you stack overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def countdown(t):
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if int(time.time()-start_time) == t:
            quit()
```

> try this.